# Jquery delete content via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a PHP application, which has a delete function on one of the pages. I am allowing user to delete a tag from their profile, by clicking on the tag. Once the user clicks the tag, the content area in the HTML which previous displayed the tags, gets updated with the new set of tags.

Now the problem is, from the list of tags,the first time user clicks a tag, it is deleted.If the user now clicks another tag(from the refreshed area), nothing happens.

```
 $("a.single_tag").click(function(){
   the_id = $(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: "data="+the_id,
         url: "<?php echo site_url('user/deletetag/');?>/",
         success: function(msg)
         {
           $("#current_tags").fadeIn("slow");
           $("#current_tags").html(msg);

         }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for this, you want [`.live('click', func)`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$("a.single_tag").live('click', function() {
```

When you use [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) you're binding a `click` handler *to those elements*, but when the content gets replaced, new elements with no handlers are there.  With [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) it listens for the `click` event when it bubbles to `document` and executes...whether the element was there when the page loaded or added later, it won't matter...fixing your issue :)

Comment: Thanks Nick. I did not know about .live event before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw that chunk of binding code in a function, and call it in the success callback, or only update the HTML of the updated tags (that is, return an id to delete, or a block of html to append, instead of redisplaying the whole block).

When you update the content, the `.click` binding does not exist on the new `a` tags.

Edit: @Nick Craver's solution is much better.

Answer (score 0):

This is because new html tags that you just  received from the server, did not have your "delete" function bound to them on click.